# Pride of Colombia Coffee from NY

Tags: ground-coffee

This coffee may be over 60 years old and never opened. The company is no longer around and there is no info on the internet. Anyone have any ideas to help me out.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to coffee! I'm not sure what your question is, what is it you want users to help you out with?

Comment: Yeah lol. I guess I wanted to try to find out if anyone had ever seen this coffee and also if it may be worth something since it’s unopened.

Comment: Could you please upload a higher resolution image, so that all of the text, including text on the back side if there is any, can be read.

Comment: And please orient the image correctly, so we can read it without getting stiff necks.

Comment: Ad in 1967 paper (http://www.digifind-it.com/woodbridge/DATA/LeaderPress/1967/1967-02-16.pdf - The Middlesex County Leader Press, page 20) shows 3 lbs of "Pride of Columbia 100% Columbian Coffee" for $1.89 a can. At Two Guys on route 9 in Woodbridge.